# Debugger does not execute the changed/latest plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I was trying to debug a plugin and the debug configurations does not execute the modified plugins. However the plugins view show the latest version of the plugins have been loaded. It some how chache's the bad/old jars. To confirm the same I have changed sysout statements. But none of the changed sysout statements are seen in the console. I see the new plugin versions are loaded but just not executed in runtime. I have tried a number of options.

1. Changed the plugin version to from 1.0.0.23 to 1.1
2. Started eclipse with -clean
3. Deleted the .metadata and runtime-application folders and reimported the plugin projects.

However after a lot of try and error, I found that if I change the workspace folder name then it would pick up the changes.

This means the workspace path is getting cached.

Does anybody have a solution?